# How to retrieve all rows in a table where the value in two specific columns are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, row

I want to retrieve all rows in a table where the values in the column RecipCodeCmte are NOT the same as those in the column RecipCodeIndiv. Both these columns live in the same table (which is called test). Here is my attempt at building such a query:

```
select *
from test
EXCEPT RecipCodeCmte=RecipCodeIndiv
```

Here is the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'RecipCodeCmte'.
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`, `<>`.

Comment: How would you write a query for when the values were equal? Or when the value in one column were equal to some constant?

Comment: @mustaccio I would write `WHERE RecipCodeCmte = RecipCodeIndiv`

Comment: That's not at all what except is used for. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Comment: @mustaccio is the correct answer `WHERE NOT RecipCodeCmte = RecipCodeIndiv` ?

Comment: Considering that "not the same as" means "not equal to", do you think you can modify the "equal" example to its opposite?

Comment: Look at @GordonLinoff first comment.... please!

Comment: @WEI_DBA and @mustaccio so the answer is  `WHERE RecipCodeCmte <> RecipCodeIndiv` ?

Comment: Try it and see.... in response to `@WEI_DBA and @mustaccio so the answer is WHERE RecipCodeCmte <> RecipCodeIndiv ? `. Your syntax is wrong, and a where clause is one of the most basic parts of SQL so it'd be wise to read up on this.

Comment: @scsimon my syntax is wrong? So I did it wrong then? I just ran it in a query though and it worked. If the syntax is really wrong and it is not doing what I think it is doing I need to know.

Comment: @scsimon read the first two sentences in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because comments are getting long...

```
select *
from test
where RecipCodeCmte <> RecipCodeIndiv
```

You can also use `!=` though `<>` is more commonly accepted.

[EXCEPT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) is used when you want to exclude based on another table. i.e.

```
select id
from table1
except
select id
from table2
```

This would return ID's that are only in table1 (which are not also in table2)

Comment: How is that different from the where clause I wrote in the comments?

Comment: It's not, that's why I insisted that you run it. @anang